# Is it true that every basis of a vector space V is a subset of V?

Tags: vector-spaces

If it were true, how would one prove it? In my textbook the definition of a basis for V is simply that it is linearly independent and V is dependent on it. There is no mentioning of it being a subset relation so I think the subset relation to be logically implied by those two conditions.

I want to use the result to prove that every basis for an n-dimensional vector space has n elements as it would shorten the proof significantly. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is a subset since every basis vector of $V$ belongs to $V$? Also a basis of an $n$-dimensional vector has $n$ vectors since this is the defintion of the dimension.

Comment: I do not know the textbook that you are referring but generally, the definition of a basis of a vector space is  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Definition)  definition given in Wikipedia.

Comment: I think your question is OK, but you should give a reference to your book. I'd find it quite hard to give the definition of a basis without implying that its elements belong to the vector space. For a more pedantic point, see my comment on MilesB's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a basis of $V$ is defined I think it's normally stated that the basis is a subset of $V$.  The question is if we take the following as the only given properties of a set $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$ is that sufficient to deduce that the set is a basis for $V$?

1. For all $v \in V$ there exist scalars $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ such that $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n = v$
2. If scalars $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ satisfy $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... a_nx_n=0$ then $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=0$

A counter-example shows that the answer is no.

Consider $W = \large \{\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}: x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Consider the subspace of $W$ defined as $V=\large \{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ (so $V$ is a vector space).

Then $X=\large \{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\}$ is clearly not a subset of $V$ but does satisfy the above conditions:

1. Given $v \in V$, let $v=  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and then $x\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+-x\cdot\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=v$
2. Given scalars $a_1, a_2$ such that $a_1\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+a_2\cdot\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =0$ it is easily seen that since $-a_2=0, a_1+a_2=0$ then $a_1=a_2=0$

So, as well as requiring linear independence and a spanning property, a careful definition of a basis should state explicitly that the basis is a subset of the vector space.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. For record: the basis of a vector space must be a subset of the vector space (by definition). Subset relation cannot be deduced from those two conditions mentioned in my textbook. So, subset relation should have been explicitly stated.

Comment: You have grasped exactly the point I was making.

Comment: Your restatement of the problem only makes sense if the vector space operations on $V$ are somehow magically extended to objects outside $V$. If you look carefully at the definition of a vector space, you will see that its operations are only defined for its elements. We (and you) are using an (incredibly convenient) abuse of notation when we use the same symbol for the vector space operations on your $W$ as we do on its subspace $V$. So if you want to be pedantic, please beware that others can be even more pedantic $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan thank you for this comment, which adds on to the clarity of the problem. For record: If $B$ is a basis for $V$, then every vector in $V$ is definable by a linear combination of the vectors in $B$. The addition operator in the linear combination is defined on the elements of $V$. So, if an element of the basis $B$ is not in $V$, then the expression of vectors in $V$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$ consists of an undefined operation. Hence, if $B$ is a basis, all its elements must be in the vector space.

Comment: @RobArthan - there's no "magical extension" going on. $W$ is a perfectly well-defined vector space, and it's no abuse to say subspace $V$ shares the same operations as $W$.  I am specifically saying that my $X$ is NOT a basis for $V$ - clearly not as it's a subset of $W$ but not a subset of $V$.  I just wanted to show that you could have a set which was linearly independent in $V$ and spanned $V$ but that didn't mean it was a basis.

Answer (score 3):

How about: Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for the vector space $V$. Then, for any scalars $a_1,...,a_n$ we have that:

$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...a_nv_n \in V$$

We want to show that every element of our basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is contained in $V$. To show that $v_k \in V$, let $a_i=0$ for $i \neq k$ and $a_k=1$.

Then we have that:

$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...a_nv_n = 0v_1+...+v_k+...+0v_n = v_k \in V$$

Comment: This is what I would have done. I recall in my algebra class that any linear combination of the vectors in the basis belong to the vector space. In my textbook, however, the basis is defined to be (1) Linearly independent set and (2) The vector space is dependent on it where this is defined as that every vector in the vector space could be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in the basis. In other words, the definition in the textbook does not necessarily state that every linear combination of it is in the vector space. Is my textbook's definition of basis inadequate?

Comment: I don't think this approach is quite right, because while a basis means that for all $v \in V$ there exist scalars such that $v = a_1v_1+ ... a_nv_n$, I don't the usual definition states that for all scalars, $a_1v_1 + ... a_nv_n \in V$.  Obviously, if the $\{v_i\}$ are a subset of $V$ then this will be true, but the subset property is what we are being asked to deduce.